# Audio error in React.js App: The element has no supported sources

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This app should play a sound when a button is clicked. Here's the code I'm working with.

```
function WordCard(props){

    let wordAudio = new Audio(props.audio)
    wordAudio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    const play = () => {
        wordAudio.play()
        .then(console.log("Working"))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    return (
        <>
        <Card >
            <button onClick={play}>
                <h1>{props.word}</h1>
            </button>
            
        </Card>
        </>
    )
}
```

At the moment, the console prints both "Working" as well as the error "DOMException: The element has no supported sources" and the audio does not play. I tried setting the cross-origin to anonymous but it did not have an effect. Does anyone know what could be going wrong? Thanks!